# What to do when my question has a duplicate on another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

What should I do with my question:

[Should I use different method names or overload parameters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134511/should-i-use-different-method-names-or-overload-parameters-in-java)

Since it appears to have been answered on another Stack Exchange site:

[Should we rename overloaded methods?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132369/should-we-rename-overloaded-methods)

I didn't search Programmers (although, it would be nice if Stack Overflow did that for me when I write out the questions title). The reason I haven't closed the question outright is because I think it's still a valid Stack Overflow question, but maybe I'm wrong about that.

What course of action is the norm in this case?